# Derivative of sum over sum?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Consider the following expression:

$$f(r)=\sum_{t=1}^T\frac{c}{(1+r)^t\sum_{k=1}^T\frac{c}{(1+r)^k}}\cdot t$$

with $c,r,T>0$.

Is it true, that $f(r)$ is decreasing in $r$?

I.e. $f(0)\geq f(r),\quad \forall r>0$?

Comment: It is unclear what this sum is meant to be. You use the index $t$ twice.

Comment: You are actually asking wheather $f(0)$ is the maximum of $f$ aren't you?

Comment: I edited the index and the question can be also seen as looking for an upper bound/ global maximum/derivative.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* The function can be considerably simplified, which should ease the analysis of monotonicity.

In the following I use for convenience only $f_T$ instead of $f$ to indicate the dependency of the parameter $T>0$.

> Observe that the inner sum does not depend on the index $t$ of the outer sum and can so be factored out. We obtain for $c,r,T>0$
>   \begin{align*}
> f_T(r)&=\sum_{t=1}^T\frac{c}{(1+r)^t\sum_{k=1}^T\frac{c}{(1+r)^k}}\cdot t\\
> &=\left(\sum_{k=1}^T\frac{1}{(1+r)^k}\right)^{-1}\sum_{t=1}^T\frac{t}{(1+r)^t}\tag{1}\\
> &=\left(\frac{\frac{1}{1+r}-\left(\frac{1}{1+r}\right)^{T+1}}{1-\frac{1}{1+r}}\right)^{-1}\sum_{t=1}^T\frac{t}{(1+r)^t}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{r}{1-\left(\frac{1}{1+r}\right)^{T}}\sum_{t=1}^T\frac{t}{(1+r)^t}\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{r(1+r)^{T}}{(1+r)^T-1}\sum_{t=1}^T\frac{t}{(1+r)^t}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we cancel $c$ and factor out the inner sum.
- In (2) we apply the formula for the *[finite geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)*.
- In (3) and (4) we do some simplifications.

Now we derive a closed formula for the series in (4).

> We obtain from (4) with $q:=\frac{1}{1+r}$
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{t=1}^T\frac{t}{(1+r)^t}&=\sum_{t=1}^Ttq^t
> =q\cdot\sum_{t=1}^Ttq^{t-1}
> =q\cdot\frac{d}{dq}\left(\sum_{t=1}^Tq^t\right)\\
> &=q\cdot\frac{d}{dq}\left(\frac{1-q^{T+1}}{1-q}\right)\\
> &=q\cdot\frac{Tq^{T+1}-(T+1)q^{T}+1}{\left(1-q\right)^2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{1+r}\cdot\frac{T\left(\frac{1}{1+r}\right)^{T+1}-(T+1)\left(\frac{1}{1+r}\right)^T+1}{\left(1-\frac{1}{1+r}\right)^2}\\
> &=\frac{1+r}{r^2}\cdot\left(T\left(\frac{1}{1+r}\right)^{T+1}-(T+1)\left(\frac{1}{1+r}\right)^T+1\right)\\
> \end{align*}

$$ $$

> Putting this in (4) we obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> f_T(r)&=\frac{1}{r}\cdot\frac{(1+r)^{(T+1)}}{(1+r)^T-1}\cdot\left(T\left(\frac{1}{1+r}\right)^{T+1}-(T+1)\left(\frac{1}{1+r}\right)^T+1\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{r}\cdot\frac{(1+r)^{T+1}-(1+T)r-1}{(1+r)^{T}-1}\\
> &=1+\frac{1}{r}-\frac{T}{(1+r)^T-1}
> \end{align*}

*Note:* The derivation of $f_T$ assumes $r>0$ according to the stated problem. We get 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\left(1+\frac{1}{r}-\frac{T}{(1+r)^T-1}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(T+1\right)
\end{align*}
which coincides with $f_T$ evaluated at $r=0$.

Comment: I am not sure if this is correct, because for $r=0$ I get a different solution: $$f(r)=\sum_{t=1}^T\frac{c}{(1+r)^t\sum_{k=1}^T\frac{c}{(1+r)^k}}\cdot t
\stackrel{r=0}{=}\frac{\sum_{t=1}^Tt}{\sum_{t=1}^T1}
=\frac{\frac{1}{2}T(T+1)}{T}=\frac{1}{2}(T+1)$$

Comment: @emcor: We assume $r>0$ according to the stated problem.

Comment: Yes but the equations should still hold.

Comment: @emcor: I've added some information which might be helpful. Note that in the derivation of $f$ I put $q:=\frac{1}{1+r}$ which gives $q=1$ when setting $r=0$. This invalidates the expression $\frac{d}{dq}\left(\frac{1-q^{T+1}}{1-q}\right)$ since with $r=1$ we have a division by zero. So, the derivation is valid for $r,T>0$ but *not* for $r=0$. This special case needs therefore to be considered separately. We could do this e.g. by a limit calculation as I did in my  note at the end.

Comment: For the function to be *decreasing*, the sign of the derivative must be negative.  I believe for the last step it is required to show that $1/r$ decreases faster than $-1/(1+r)^T$ increases (with $T\geq1$ since it is an integer)? Otherwise the function is increasing, which might be possible.

Comment: @emcor: I think the simplification stated here is sufficient. The analysis of monotonicity needs a little bit more calculation (... and better than mine before :-;) but I'm pretty sure, you will master it. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

OK, first of all $c>0$ serves nothing at all, you may erase it. I can't think anything better than differentiating $f$ and showing it is decreasing. So, you know that you can take the derrivative of a sum by taking the respective derrivatives of its terms; appyling this rule and what you know about differentiating quotients you obtain
$$f'(r) = {\operatorname{d}\over\operatorname{d}\!r} \displaystyle{\sum_{t=1}^T \frac{t}{\sum_{k=1}^T \frac{(1+r)^t}{(1+r)^k}}} = {\operatorname{d}\over\operatorname{d}\!r} \displaystyle{\sum_{t=1}^T \frac{t}{\sum_{k=1}^T (1+r)^{t-k}}} = \displaystyle{\sum_{t=1}^T \frac{-t \cdot {\operatorname{d}\over\operatorname{d}\!r} \sum_{k=1}^T (1+r)^{t-k}}{(\sum_{k=1}^T (1+r)^{t-k})^2}} = $$ $$= \displaystyle{\sum_{t=1}^T \frac{-t \cdot {\operatorname{d}\over\operatorname{d}\!r} \sum_{k=1}^T (1+r)^{t-k}}{(\sum_{k=1}^T (1+r)^{t-k})^2}} = \displaystyle{\sum_{t=1}^T \frac{-t \cdot \sum_{k=1}^T (t-k)(1+r)^{t-k-1}}{(\sum_{k=1}^T (1+r)^{t-k})^2}} = \displaystyle{\sum_{t=1}^T \frac{t(1+r)^{t-1} \sum_{k=1}^T \frac{(t-k)}{(1+r)^{k}}}{(\sum_{k=1}^T (1+r)^{k-t})^2}}.$$
Wow! After all these, we just need to make sure that  that $f' \leq 0$ (thus $f$ is decreasing). I'm not going to give a rigorous argument for that (please, have mercy on me!) but you may notice that for the terms of the sum with index $t < \frac{T}{2}$ we have $\sum_{k=1}^T \frac{(t-k)}{(1+r)^{k}} \leq 0$ and the fraction
$$\frac{t(1+r)^{t-1}}{(\sum_{k=1}^T (1+r)^{k-t})^2}$$
is relatively large, compaired to the case where $t < \frac{T}{2}$, in which we also get $\sum_{k=1}^T \frac{(t-k)}{(1+r)^{k}} \geq 0$.

Good luck with this! Hopefully I'm wrong and there is some easiest way... (And hopefully I didn't mess up while differentiating!)

Comment: Thank you for your derivation. Can you maybe plot the function $f(r)$ or $f'(r)$ to show that it is decreasing in $r$? E.g. assume $T=10$ and use WolframAlpha for plotting.

Comment: @emcor I must say I'm not a fan of plotting; but in any case that is a quite complex function, I don't think that a plot would help. The actual goal is to test your convinience with multiple sums and all this peculiar symbolism; such things are not so easy for computers (and that's the reason why we can still have a job!)